# View Event parameters from events older than 30 minutes in Google Analytics (2021)

Tags: google-analytics, hyperlink, analytics, outbound

I am trying to track links users click on my site.
I am able to see the links they are clicking on by going to `Engagement -> Events -> Click -> link_url(Under parameter name),` however I can not find a way to view this data after 30 minutes. After 30 minutes I can just view the number of clicks, but it wont let me view the **link_url**.

I have turned on the "**Enhanced Tracking–Outbound Links**", but similar to the previous I cannot find a way to view the url of the clicks.

I saw in SO answers that used Older GA versions to go to Behavior->Events, to access this data, however I can't seem to find the equivalent now.

How can I view what links my users are clicking on after 30 minutes?

[image: GA Dashboard Photo]

Answer (score 15):

I was dealing with the same problem recently. To see the data like link_url, file_name etc. you need to create custom dimensions (Events > Manage custom dimensions > Create custom dimensions). After creating desired dimemension, you will have to wait 24 hours to see them in your reports.

See section  "Register event parameters as custom dimensions (this applies even to Recommended Events)" at this website - https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/recommended-events-in-google-analytics-4/

Comment: I don't see "Manage Custom Definitions" button in the Events Page in Google Analytics anymore. Can anyone help?

Comment: @AsadAliChoudhry in the latest version (10 Feb 2022) you can find it at Configure -> Custom definitions -> Create custom dimensions

Comment: Step by step for Google Analytics 4: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829#zippy=%2Cin-this-article